# Javascript events onkeyXXX does not work on icefaces 1.8.2 ice:selectinputtext

Tags: javascript, java, jsf, dom-events, icefaces

I have an JSF + icefaces 1.8.2 application which has a "ice:selectInputText".

I wanted to add just one of the following Javascript events: onkeydown, onkeypress or onkeyup.
However they do not work.
They do nothing, they are not even in the HTML code of the web when it renders in the browser.

Is this how it is supposed to work?

I want to know when the "return" key (Javascript keycode 13) is pressed, so I cannot use the Java `valueChangeListener` or `textChangeListener` and then manage it in the Java backbean because this key does not fire those events.

Can anybody help me please?

Answer (score 0):

It is supposed to work:

HTML:

```
<ice:selectInputText
<!-- your stuff -->
onkeypress="check(event);"
</ice:selectInputText>
```

JavaScript:

```
   function check(e) {

       var key;
       if(!window.event) {
           key = e.which;
       } else {
          key = window.event.keyCode;
       }

       if(key == 13) {
          alert('enter!');
       }
    }
```

Comment: Hi! As far as I have tried that does not work, neither the onkeypress, nor the onkeydown, nor the onkeyup events.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it!! Well... somebody gave me a way to solve it.

Pressing the return key, fires the ice:selectInputText "action", so then I can manage it through java in the back bean

Answer (score 0):

I assume from your problem description that the tag id is an argument for the js function. In which case I've been fighting with the same problem.

In my case I wanted my custom script to limit user input. When outputting HTML, Icefaces changes the id of the tag. It appends the containing form id to the tag id as a prefix and appends, in the case of an ace:textEntry tag '**_input**' as a suffix. So the id for my ace:textEntry tag became '**customer-edit-form:company-name-text_input**'. To get around this use **this.id**.

Markup for working Tag:

```
<ice:form id="customer-edit-form">
    <ace:textEntry styleClass = "edit-textbox" 
        id="company-name-text1" 
        label="Company"
        labelPosition="left" 
        onkeyup="limitLengthByID(this.id, '4'); "
        value="#{customerManagerBean.companyName}">
    </ace:textEntry>
</ice:form>**strong text**
```